# Want to get both tables from the web page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I am trying to get it by using class name. but getting none in response.

Here is the code:

```
from requests import get
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

url = 'https://www.hydraulichoses.com/sae100-r2s-2-wire-hydraulic-hoses-p/r2s.htm'

soup = BeautifulSoup( requests.get(url).content, 'lxml')

product_category = ''

product_category = soup.find('td', class_ = 'vCSS_breadcrumb_td').findAll('a')[1].text.strip()

product_title = soup.find('td', class_ = 'vCSS_breadcrumb_td').find('h1').text

print(soup.find('table', class_ = 'product-table'))
```

I want to get these two table's from the page:
**This is first table**
[image]

**Here is the second table:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tables don't have class or id, so you need to search for them in some other way.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.hydraulichoses.com/sae100-r2s-2-wire-hydraulic-hoses-p/r2s.htm'
soup = BeautifulSoup( requests.get(url).content, 'lxml')

first_table = soup.find('span', id='product_description').find_next('table')
second_table = soup.find('span', id='technical').find_next('table', width='98%')

# print them on screen:

for tr in first_table.select('tr'):
    print(*[td.get_text(strip=True, separator=' ') for td in tr.select('td, th')])

print('-' * 80)

for tr in second_table.select('tr'):
    print(*[td.get_text(strip=True, separator=' ') for td in tr.select('td, th')])
```

Prints:

```
Item# Item Name Our Price Qty Add
R2S-04 100R2S-04  - 1/4" R2  Hydraulic Hose (per foot) $1.40  
R2S-04-REEL 100R2S-04-Reel  - 1/4" R2  Hydraulic Hose - 500 feet $670.36  
R2S-06 100R2S-06  - 3/8" R2  Hydraulic Hose (per foot) $1.67  
R2S-06-REEL 100R2S-06-Reel  - 3/8" R2  Hydraulic Hose - 450 feet $721.91  
R2S-08 100R2S-08  - 1/2" R2  Hydraulic Hose (per foot) $1.85  
R2S-08-REEL 100R2S-08-Reel  - 1/2" R2  Hydraulic Hose - 320 feet $567.22  
R2S-10 100R2S-10  - 5/8" R2  Hydraulic Hose (per foot) $2.61  
R2S-10-REEL 100R2S-10-Reel  - 5/8" R2  Hydraulic Hose - 520 feet $1,293.67  
R2S-12 100R2S-12  - 3/4" R2  Hydraulic Hose (per foot) $2.73  
R2S-12-REEL 100R2S-12-Reel  - 3/4" R2  Hydraulic Hose - 400 feet $1,050.18  
R2S-16 100R2S-16  - 1" R2  Hydraulic Hose (per foot) $3.75  
R2S-16-REEL 100R2S-16-Reel  - 1" R2  Hydraulic Hose - 200 feet $719.22  
R2S-20 100R2S-20  - 1-1/4" R2  Hydraulic Hose (per foot) $11.65  
R2S-20-REEL 100R2S-20-Reel  - 1-1/4" R2  Hydraulic Hose - 131 feet (apprx.) $1,466.28  
R2S-24 100R2S-24  - 1-1/2" R2  Hydraulic Hose (per foot) $13.56  
R2S-24-REEL 100R2S-24-Reel  - 1-1/2" R2  Hydraulic Hose - 131 feet $1,750.30  
R2S-32 100R2S-32  - 2" R2  Hydraulic Hose (per foot) $17.23  
R2S-32-REEL 100R2S-32-Reel  - 2" R2  Hydraulic Hose - 131 feet $2,173.96  
Check the items you wish to purchase, then click
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Item # Inside Diameter Outside Diameter Working Pressure Burst Presure Bend Radius Reel Size
R2S-04 1/4" 0.59" 5,800 psi 20,000 psi 4" 500 feet
R2S-06 3/8" 0.75" 4,785psi 16,000 psi 5" 450 feet
R2S-08 1/2" 0.87" 3,990 psi 14,000 psi 7" 320 feet
R2S-10 5/8" 1.00" 3,625 psi 11,000 psi 8" 520 feet
R2S-12 3/4" 1.15" 3,120 psi 9,000 psi 9.5" 400 feet
R2S-16 1" 1.50" 2,395 psi 8,000 psi 12" 200 feet
R2S-20 1-1/4" 1.90" 1,815 psi 6,500 psi 16.5" 131 feet (apprx.)
R2S-24 1-1/2" 2.15" 1,250 psi 5,000 psi 19.5" 131 feet
R2S-32 2" 2.64" 1,125 psi 4,500 psi 25.5" 131 feet
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to find both tables in `soup` by a `css selector`

```
tables = soup.find_all('table')
```

Now you iterate in a `tables` variable grabbing the needed content.

Answer (score 0):

There are more than 2 tables in this page. You would normally need to inspect the code to see which tables you want.

```
tables=soup.findAll("table")
print(len(tables))
#outputs: 12
```

In your case, you seem to be after `tables[7]` and `tables[11]`.